# ngChecked to deselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Is it possible to use ngChecked on a checkbox that you want to have deselect all other checked checkboxes. Below is an example of what I'd like to do except that the functionality **selects all** I want to deselect all

#### http://plnkr.co/edit/iseIU1OIjocW4nXTN6ru?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example54-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master"><br />
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master"><br />
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master"><br />
  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"> <b>Check me to select all:</b><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: like this:http://plnkr.co/edit/W1fEkSzHIqsdRsZGVjU9?p=preview?

Comment: Josep, you have 3 instances of a single ID there, which is invalid.

Comment: that worked for me. I forked and updated a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/k18M8mSvZlzwr8ZsYtyJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do ! (not) on the ng-checked to achieve the opposite

```html
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="!master"><br />
```